LinkedIn API - Server 500 Error on some pages
I have a wordpress site built with a custom theme - I'm having problems getting previews to show while sharing some pages on LinkedIn (while they work fine in Facebook)
Using the LinkedIn Post Inspector some of the pages come back with a 500 error and some don't.
These are the things I've tried

Looked at the server logs - not found anything obvious.
Made sure that the page is valid HTML.
Increased the PHP memory limit.
Made sure the page has the right doc type and that there aren't any comments after the closing tag.
Installed a caching plugin to improve performance / loading speed.
Added social meta content through the Yoast SEO plugin.

I've tried elements one by one from a page template until the Post Inspector no longer returns a 500 error, but so far I haven't found a pattern to what is causing it.
Is there anything else I can try?
It can't be an SSL issue if only some of the pages are returning a 500?

I went back and had another go, putting the page markup into a static HTML file and removing / replacing random pieces of content till it passed.
In the end I narrowed it down to a single date string in the content. If it was 12/06/2024 it would pass but "June 12, 2024" or "12 June, 2024" would fail.
I wondered if it was a mismatch with some of the Yoast meta tags / schema but removing all of those and leaving the date still failed.
I tried putting the date in a time tag but that didn't work.
Only solution I could find was to output the date with JS:
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('June 18, 2024');
</script>
<noscript>June 18, 2024</noscript>

I have no idea what the issue was but hopefully this might help someone with the same problem.
When the page did pass it would say 'No publication date found' but Linkedin offer no guidance on how to fix that, all the meta tags I tried failed to get rid of that warning. So don't know if that was also causing issues.
